# Anyone could explaing how to add new recipe with react and axios?

Tags: reactjs

[Full code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/ackee)Okay so I am trying to add new recipe to recipes but it wont work, the recipe isnt adding. I am not really sure how it works with axios.post either. It is not throwing error anyway.Not sure if my way is really the way . I really appreaciate any advice. Thanks

Recipe.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import './Form.css'
    import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
    import {useContext,useState} from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    function Form() {
        const [nazev,setNazev]=useState('');
        const[uvodni,setUvodni]=useState('');
        const[ingredience,setIngredience]=useState('');
        const[postup,setPostup]=useState('');
        const[time,setTime]=useState(0);
        const [score,setScore]=useState(0);
        const{recipes,setRecipes}=useContext(RecipeContext)
        const onSubmit=e=>{
          const newRecipe={id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
          description:postup,name:nazev,duration:time,info:uvodni,score:+score}
          
          e.preventDefault()
          setRecipes([...recipes,newRecipe])
          axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes")
             
        
        }
        
        return (
            <>
            <button className="pridat" onClick={onSubmit}>+</button>
            <form className="form" >
              <p className="nazev">Název receptu</p>
              <input type="text" value={nazev}
              onChange={(e) => setNazev(e.target.value)}/>
              <input type="text" className="uvodni" placeholder="Úvodní text"
              value={uvodni}
              onChange={(e) => setUvodni(e.target.value)}/>
              <h2>Ingredience</h2>
              <input placeholder="Vaše ingredience" type="text"
              value={ingredience}
              onChange={(e) => setIngredience(e.target.value)}/>
              <button>+ Přidat</button>
              <input type="text" className="postup" placeholder="Postup"
              value={postup}
              onChange={(e) => setPostup(e.target.value)}/>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Čas" className="cas" value={time}
              onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}/>
            </form>
            </>
        )
              }

export default Form
```

RecipeContext.js

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,createContext,useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'


export const RecipeContext=createContext([[],() => {}]);

export default function RecipeProvider(props) {
    const[recipes,setRecipes]=useState([])
    const[state,dispatch]=useReducer(AppReducer,recipes)
    function addRecipe(id){
      dispatch({
        type:'ADD_RECIPE',
        payload:id
      })
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes?limit=10&offset=0')
  .then(res=>setRecipes(res.data))
  console.log(recipes)
    })   

    
  

    
    return (
       
<RecipeContext.Provider value={{recipes,setRecipes,addTransaction}}>
    {props.children}
</RecipeContext.Provider>
      
    )
}
```

AppReducer.js

```
export default (state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
  
        case 'ADD_RECIPE':
            return{
                ...state,
                recipes:[action.payload,...state.recipes]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to update state in react or add a recipe via axios in the api?

Comment: I wanna add the recipe so it displays along the others

Comment: Do you want recipe to be seen in the console.log?

Comment: nope, not really

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any data to the server. With the POST method, you have to send the data and then update the state with the response. It should be something like this:

```
     axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes", newRecipe)
      .then(res => setRecipes(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

If you still get an error, then the problem is something else.

Comment: Yeah it got shown in the console but hasnt been added

Comment: yeah now the error on submit is 500,any idea?